# Meteor test if user is role admin

Tags: javascript, meteor

I've add the alanning:roles package on my Meteor projet for setting role on my user.

I add my first user with this fixtures :

```
if (Meteor.users.find().count() === 0) {

  const adminUsername = "username";
  const adminPassword = "password";

  const adminAccount = Accounts.createUser({
    username: adminUsername,
    password: adminPassword
  });

  Roles.addUsersToRoles(adminAccount, 'admin', Roles.GLOBAL_GROUP);

}
```

And i test if the user is admin with this :

```
const testAdmin = Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.userId(), 'admin', Roles.GLOBAL_GROUP);

console.log(testAdmin); // return false, why ?
```

My console.log off testAdmin return false, and i don't understand why :/ On mongoDb, i see this :

```
"roles" : {
    "__global_roles__" : [
        "admin"
    ]
}
```

So, my user has been admin role. Why my test don't return true ?

Anyone can help me ?

Thank you community !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try if it works at least on Server side.

If so, it means you just need to publish the `roles` field of `Meteor.users` as well. Meteor does not publish all user data even with `autopublish` package.

Comment: Yes, it work on server side, not on client :) Thank you for your help !

Comment: so how to make it works in client without `autopublish` i already publish `users` and `roles`, but it still not works

Comment: Hi @yozawiratama, please feel free to open a new question with details of your specific issue.